# не проходит тест на action new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**items_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @item = current_user.items.build
end
```

> проблема с be_a_new(Item)

**items_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ItemsController, type: :controller do
  describe '#new' do
    let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    subject { response }

    before do
      session[:current_user_id] = user.token
      get :new
    end

    it { expect(assigns(:item).user).to be_a_new(Item) }
    it { is_expected.to have_http_status :ok }
    it { is_expected.to render_template('new') }
  end
end
```

**log**

http://pastebin.com/dm7eh2wJ

Comment: `it { expect(assigns(:item).user).to be_a_new(Item) }` вы проверяете, что `.user` класса `Item`?

Comment: я хотел проверить через ассоциацию, но теперь уже понял что местами перепутал

Comment: Так что, всё, разобрались? Отладчик, кстати, освоили?

Comment: @D-side, с тестом уже разобрался, использую pry, но когда в тестах пишу бинд, то при попытке  вывести значиние из let, появляется ошибка, так что с дебагом в тесках еще не разобрался

Comment: @АндрейШостик как вы пишите бинд в лет?